# Can't Move / Delete PDF after processing with pdfrw

Tags: python, pdfrw

I've updated the question to contain the bulk of the code as I feel there may be some of it that is blocking each other...
Can be tested by simply adding a pdf file or two to your c:\temp folder (on windows).
I've just started with Python so may be missing basic stuff...

```
import glob
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF4
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter


def safe_open_pdf(pdf):
    pdf_reader = None
    result = True

    file = open(pdf, 'rb')
    try:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(file)
        result = True
    except:
        # some older PDF files on my disk raise a missing EOF error, which cannot be handled by PyPDF4
        print(pdf.split('\\')[-1] + " needs to be fixed")
        result = False

    if not result:
        # if file had EOF error, I "rebuild" it with PdfReader and PdfWriter
        x = PdfReader(pdf)
        y = PdfWriter()
        y.addpages(x.pages)
        y.write(pdf)
        pdf_reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(file)

    return pdf_reader


def move_processed_pdf(source_file):
    Path(new_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    print("Copying to " + new_path + new_file)

    f = open(PDFFile, 'rb')
    x = PdfReader(f)
    y = PdfWriter()
    y.addpages(x.pages)
    y.write(new_path + new_file)

    f.close()
    # time.sleep(5)
    Path(PDFFile).unlink()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    relevant_path = 'C:\\temp\\'
    file_count = 0
    new_path = 'C:\\temp\\processed\\'

    for PDFFile in glob.iglob(relevant_path + '*.pdf', recursive=True):

        new_file = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + PDFFile.split('\\')[-1]

        print('Processing File: ' + PDFFile.split('\\')[-1])

        pdfReader = safe_open_pdf(PDFFile)
        file_count += 1
        num_pages = pdfReader.numPages

        print(num_pages)

        page_count = 0
        text = ''

        while page_count < num_pages:
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page_count)
            page_count += 1
            text += pageObj.extractText()

        # Main processing occurs here

        move_processed_pdf(PDFFile)
```

the issue I get is `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`.

folders and files exist.

any ideas?

Comment: Latest pdfrw might read from path with `PdfReader(PDFFile)` and manual manipulation with open/close not needed. Did you try to `unlink` on first line to check that you've this rights?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, yes I have checked rights.
This is just snip of whole procedure, could issue instead lie with 
for PDFFile in glob.iglob(relevant_path + '*.pdf', recursive=True):

Comment: make sure the file exists before un-linking. put it on a try/catch

Comment: Hi I have tested both, no luck:
If i put unlink before the "print("copying to...")" line, it throws the same error
And file does exist, as it is being picked up in the loop